# Antonym for 'preaching to the choir'

Tags: phrases, antonyms

I'm looking for a phrase which essentially means questioning a belief you share with someone, but that other person has an almost unshakable faith in that belief, so your misgivings fall on deaf ears or they try and convince you otherwise without really taking into consideration your points.

Not necessarily religious, but it could be for instance, questioning the negative impact of legal weapons to a friend in the NRA

Comment: Singing to the preacher?

Comment: "Like talking to an NRA member"?

Comment: I was thinking of "quixotic" in some form.

Comment: "Preaching to deaf ears."

Comment: @Karen I've heard it as "Preaching to the Deaf;" deaf is a nice antonym to a choir in addition to stripping some of the religious connotation. But apparently that's the name of a metal song, so I can't say if I heard it from there or in actual common usage.

Comment: @PatrickM I don't know if I've ever heard "preaching to deaf ears", but it's a nice combination of "X fell on deaf ears" and "preaching to the choir" that captures the intent quite nicely.  It someone's not familiar with both idioms, though, it might, heh, fall on deaf ears.

Comment: You could probably use 'being obnoxiously closed-minded' as a direct substitute.  For instance, instead of: 'I was telling my friend in the NRA how guns are bad,' you could instead say: 'I was being obnoxiously closed-minded.'  HTH  ;-)

Comment: It's like preaching vegetarianism to a family of hyenas.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use the expression ***it's like talking to a brick wall***.

It's an established idiom listed in some [dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/be-like-talking-to-a-brick-wall), and it means that you can't get through to the other person.

Another applicable expression might be ***teaching a pig to sing***, from a quote attributed to [Heinlein](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/never_try_to_teach_a_pig_to_sing-it_wastes_your/218581.html) – especially if you find yourself getting frustrated in your efforts.

Comment: If this is not the best answer, I don't know what

Comment: And if you are frustrated with your best efforts and disgusted with the reception, you could say you are casting "pearls before swine".

Answer (score 9):

[Waste one's breath](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/waste+breath) may fit the context:  ( from TFD)

> - to waste one's time talking; to talk in vain. Don't waste your breath talking to her. She won't listen. You can't persuade me. You're just wasting your breath.
> - tell or ask someone something although this will have no effect (often negative) Don't waste your breath. I've already asked her to help and she said no. You'd be wasting your breath reporting it to the police - they never look for stolen bikes.

Answer (score 6):

Most other answers give good idioms specifically for futile conversation. In addition to these, a more general (and perhaps fancier-sounding) phrase that applies here is *an exercise in futility*. It means nothing will change in spite of the action you're taking.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for -

"Being the devil's advocate" -  advocating an opposing view (that you may or may not support but the listener firmly does) , often for the sake of argument (opposing for the sake of argument)

The above seems to mean the opposite of the idiom :

"Preaching to the choir"- to make one's case primarily to one's supporters (convincing in vain);

Comment: I don't think this is antonymic, really.

Comment: Antonyms to an idiom are quite context specific really.

Comment: I think that "being the devil's advocate" has a specific meaning which takes it into a different context: the devil's advocate doesn't necessarily believe or agree with the position they're taking, but they take that position deliberately to more fully explore the issue.    So the devil's advocate isn't really advocating a position at all, which makes it **neither** the same as or the opposite to "preaching to the choir".

Answer (score 2):

You could be said to be "banging your head against a brick wall".

More colourfully you could be said to be ["pissing into the wind"](http://urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pissing%20into%20the%20wind)

Comment: Both of these more often emphasize action leading to unintentional self-harm. The asker is only looking for an expression of futility. I wouldn't use either of these idioms to express the ideas in the question.

Comment: If taken literally they would have that meaning, but as non-literal expressions they do *not* imply self-harm, only the futility of the action itself...

Comment: *Banging your head against a wall* means you're repeating a futile attempt to the point where it's painful (I do this regularly as a programmer :)). *Pissing into the wind* means you're being careless and that's bound to make a mess of things. The former might pass as an expression of futility, but the latter has nothing to do with futility IMO.

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong about the meaning of "pissing into the wind". I offer as evidence the link in my answer. It is not about being careless whatsoever, it is about the futility of urinating into an oncoming wind because you will get it all back again.

Comment: As reputable a source as Urban Dictionary may be in some circles, I have to disagree. *Futility* means *effort accomplishing nothing*. When you piss into the wind, you accomplish your goal: relieving your bladder. The problem is being covered in urine when the wind blows it back. It's not a problem because "you were trying to get rid of your urine and now you've got it all back again", it's a problem because now you smell like piss. That has nothing to do with futility.

Comment: Fair enough- Are the Cambridge Dictionaries reputable enough for you? http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/be-pissing-in-the-wind?q=pissing+in+the+wind

Comment: Fair enough indeed. I'll concede to that on technicality, though I stand by my reasoning.

Comment: @MarvMills Doing something useless but inconsequential is 'blowing into a violin', doing something stupid (not seeing the consequences) is 'pissing into the wind'. That leaves 'pissing into a violin'.

Answer (score 2):

One expression I thought of when reading this was "Falling on deaf ears"

You mentioned it in your original post, but that's what I would use.

Answer (score 2):

**'Flogging a dead horse'** springs to mind. This is a very popular phrase here in England which means spending time and effort on something which will ultimately be fruitless.

The phrase I think stems from the idea 'beating a dead horse will not make it do any more work' (you are wasting your time).

Comment: Not really; 'flogging a dead horse' implies repetition in some fashion. But here, the OP might be being persuasive to any average person

Comment: I disagree. It implies trying to persuade something which has no chance of responding. You could compare the average person to a living horse where there would be some chance of response. I don't get the repetition link

Answer (score 1):

How about 'casting your pearls before swine'?

Answer (score 1):

I use "You are talking to the wrong end of the mule" -- although that carries the implication that the audience either cannot understand you or cannot do anything about your complaint, not that it does not agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

When I first saw "antonym of 'preaching to the choir'", I thought of "appealing to the masses".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @. 
We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).
Your post would be improved if it included a reference and an explanation of why it answers the question.

Comment: That is an opposite of "preaching to the choir" ... but not in the sense that the questioner is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

My personal favourite is:

> "A bit like reading aloud from 'Satanic Verses' in a Mosque"

... can't remember what TV-show or movie the quote is from.

Comment: A German author actually [proposed doing this](http://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/breaking-the-rushdie-taboo-german-writer-wants-to-read-satanic-verses-in-cologne-mosque-a-494360.html) in 2007, but the expression [occurred online](http://www.44342.com/linux-f1112-t2388-p1.htm) in 2003. However, this is like "waving a red flag at a bull," expecting a furious reaction, not attempting to persuade someone and finding it futile because of their intransigence.